# Deploy on Heroku found error: GET 502 Bad Gateway favicon.ico

Tags: heroku, deployment, get, mern, favicon

I have followed this tutorial and some alike but it showed me the error as title.

> https://dev.to/hawacodes/deploying-a-mern-app-with-heroku-3km7

I have also put env on heroku
[config var](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rPE0.png)

Here are my practice project github
https://github.com/NDK2020/sheyshop

And my current Heroku app
https://practice-sheyshop.herokuapp.com/

I have tried all the way, but it wasn't work. I can see the website load as in the dev environment and then the screen blank within seconds, open the network tab in Firefox it stated:
[error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBBKR.png)

Log from heroku
[Log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdiy3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer, in my server.ts, I have to put this code block after this the route declaration. From this

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  console.log("PRODUCTION MODE ACTIVE");
  //app.use('/', express.static("/client/build"));
  app.use(express.static("./client/build"));
  app.get('*', (req: any, res: any) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './client/build','index.html'));
  })
}

app.use('/api/products/', productRoute)
app.use('/api/users/', userRoute)
app.use('/api/orders/', ordersRoute);
```

To this

```
app.use('/api/products/', productRoute)
app.use('/api/users/', userRoute)
app.use('/api/orders/', ordersRoute);

  
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  console.log("PRODUCTION MODE ACTIVE");
  //app.use('/', express.static("/client/build"));
  app.use(express.static("./client/build"));
  app.get('*', (req: any, res: any) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './client/build','index.html'));
  })
}
```